# how use swift await func in onSubmit block

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, synchronous, swift5

I have a list with data from the search.
to get data I  want to call to await func (swift 5.5)  but I get this error:

> "Cannot pass function of type '() async -> ()' to parameter expecting
> synchronous function type"

this is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {


@ObservedObject var twitterAPI: TwitterAPI = TwitterAPI()

@State private var searchText = "TheEllenShow" // TheEllenShow

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            if twitterAPI.twitterSearchResults?.resultDataVM != nil{
                List {
                    ForEach((twitterAPI.twitterSearchResults?.resultDataVM)!) { item in
                        Text(item.text)
                    }
                }
                .refreshable {
                    await twitterAPI.executeQuery(userName: searchText)
                }
            }else{
                Text("Loading")
            }
            Spacer()
            
            
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .onSubmit(of: .search) {
            await twitterAPI.executeQuery(userName: searchText)
        }

        .navigationTitle("Twitter")
        
    }
    .task {
        await twitterAPI.executeQuery(userName: searchText)
    }
}  }
```

Answer (score 6):

To call asynchronous code from a synchronous code block, you can create a `Task` object:

```swift
.onSubmit(of: .search) {
  Task {
    await twitterAPI.executeQuery(userName: searchText)
  }
}
```

Comment: A lot of thanks! work as excepted!
Do you have sources that can be deepened?

Comment: @isreal_b_2012 Look for the WWDC 2021 videos on concurrency. Beyond that, the Modern Concurrency in Swift book from raywenderlich.com really goes into depth on async/await concureency, and its application within modern apps.

Comment: This has an issue that if submit is done twice, the previous task isn't cancelled

Answer (score 1):

You could bounce it over to `.task` like this:

```
@State var submittedSearch = ""
@State var results = []    

.onSubmit(of: .search) {
    submittedSearch = searchText
}
.task(id: submittedSearch) {
    if submittedSearch.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    results = await twitterAPI.executeQuery(userName: submittedSearch)
}
```

Has the advantage it will be cancelled and restarted if the search changes and also when the underlying UIView disappears.